# .htaccess redirect only specific page to https with rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to redirect my contact page to https trough .htaccess with moderewrite.

this is the url of my contact page: 
http://mywebsite.com/index.php?route=information/contact  (this is opencart website).

Which will be the correct rewrite rule to redirect this on to https ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(/index.php?route=information/contact) https://mywebsite.com$1 [L,R=301]
```

(OP asked how to do it with “mod_rewrite”)

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple "this for that" redirect:

```
Redirect 301 http://mywebsite.com/index.php?route=information/contact https://mywebsite.com/index.php?route=information/contact
```